# How to configure namespace to keep partial data as cache in ram and the remaining in hard disk?

Tags: ram, configure, partial, aerospike

I am trying to write some data to a namespace in `Aerospike`, but i don't have enough ram for the whole data. 
How can i configure my `Aerospike` so that a portion of the data in kept in the ram as cache and remaining is kept in the hard drive?
Can I reduce the number of copies of data made in `Aerospike` kept in ram? 
It can be done by modifying the contents of`aerospike.conf` file but how exactly am i going to achieve it.

Comment: Hi Vini! Thanks for your interest in Aerospike. Please feel free to ask future questions on the Aerospike forum at discuss.aerospike.com. Be sure to check out our free online training availble on our site here: http://www.aerospike.com/training

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have seen the configuration page in aerospike documentation before asking such question

http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/namespace/storage/

Comment: Thank you Sir Salman. I should be more careful next time before asking such questions. The documentation helped me alot.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i configure my Aerospike so that a portion of the data in kept in the ram as cache and remaining is kept in the hard drive?

The [post-write-queue](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#post-write-queue) parameter defines the amount of RAM to use to keep recently written records in RAM. As long as these records are still in the post-write-queue Aerospike will read directly from RAM rather than disk. This will allow you to configure a LRU cache for an namespace that is [storage-engine device](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#storage-engine) and [data-in-memory false](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#data-in-memory). Note that this is least recently updated (or created) rather than least recently used (read or write) cache eviction algorithm.